# Displaying a UIAlertView adjacent to button pressed to call

Tags: swift, uialertview

I'm trying to figure out if theres a way to tie the location a programatically created `UIAlertView` is displayed on screen to the location of the button pressed to activate it.

I would like to have my alert view display directly below my button.

Comment: You could use a popover, but not with an alertview

Comment: That will almost work, is there a way to programatically change the anchor point of a popover? to re-use one on several buttons.

Comment: You can use the sourceRect property for that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to gutenmorgenuhu for setting me on the right direction I was able to create a `UIPopover` that locates its self to the button pressed.

I first created a new `UIViewController` with the content of my popover (a `UIPickerView` in this case), that view is given the storyboard name Popover.

Then in my original view I created 2 buttons, topButton and bottomButton and linked them to their respective actions and outlets.

My code follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {


//declare variables
var popOverLocation: CGRect!

// Set outlets for all buttons
@IBOutlet weak var topButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var bottomButton: UIButton!

//Add actions to buttons, first trigger popOverLocation to take the frame properties of the active button, then call the popover function.
@IBAction func topButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    popOverLocation = topButton.frame
    popOver()
}
@IBAction func bottomButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    popOverLocation = bottomButton.frame
    popOver()
}

//function for creating the popover
func popOver() {

    //Read the height, and XY coordinates of the active button
    var h = popOverLocation.height
    var x = popOverLocation.origin.x
    var y = popOverLocation.origin.y + h

    //create the popover
    var popoverContent = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Popover") as UIViewController
    var nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: popoverContent)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    var popover = nav.popoverPresentationController! as UIPopoverPresentationController
    popover.sourceView = self.view
    popover.delegate = self

    //set the size of the popover
    popoverContent.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(200,300);

    //set the direction the popover arrow is allowed to point
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up

    //using the buttons coordinates set the location of the popover
    popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(x,y,0,0)
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```